# Отправить письмо

Tags: c++, сокет, curl, boost, c++17

Задача в следующем, мне нужно написать прогу, которая отправляла бы на указанные адреса почт моих контрагентов письма с вложениями (не спам рассылка!).

Вопрос в следующем, что использовать лучше для данной задачи? `CURL`, `boost`, велосипед? Может есть еще какие-нибудь готовые решения из `с++17`, как например `<filesystem>`? Мной было найдено в сети куча исходников, но не знаю какой набор готовых решений сейчас актуален. Кто имеет опыт, пожалуйста, посоветуйте.

Comment: велосипед (читай curl), срр тут только чтобы вызвать этот велосипед с параметрами ;)

Comment: Почему бы не отправлять все это используя обычный почтовый клиент?

Comment: @VTT - обычный почтовый клиент не умеет, например, формировать акты сверок через 1с -))) и много другого, да и стандартный набор функций почтового клиента мне не подходит

Comment: Вы явно недооцениваете возможности почтовых клиентов...

Comment: @asianirish , да вот не хотелось бы, хотя я очень люблю это делать, возможно, это можно реализовать с помощью php и с++, это вервый велосипед, что приходит в голову )

Comment: @VTT - почтовый клиент, создан для работы с почтой и только - мне нужно больше, готовых решений не могу найти, поэтому буду мастерить своими руками